# How to concat json files with jq?

Tags: arrays, json, file, jq

I'd like to take 50 or so json files, and simply concat them with jq.

Files look like this

`file-1.json`

```
{
  "name": "john"
}
```

`file-2.json`

```
{
  "name": "Xiaoming"
}
```

I want one file

`file-all.json`

That looks like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Xiaoming"
  },
  {
    "name": "Xiaoming"
  }
]
```

An array of all the other files.

How do I do that? : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files are named following a sequence like in your example, then you can use this:

```
jq -s '.' file-{1..50}.json > file-all.json
```

Comment: That's great. And how do I get the output into a file? `| cat`? or something like that? Sorry, not a bash pro.

Comment: That doesn't put all the objects into a single array. It just echos each one individually.

Comment: @Shawn - Your answer is fine, but it would help avoid confusion if you deleted the inaccurate comment above. Thanks.

Comment: @Shawn You are missing the `-s` option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of the objects from those files combined in a single array:

```
jq -n '[inputs]' file-{1..50}.json > file-all.json
```